# What is the fastest way to copy a block-aligned extent from one file to annother on FreeBSD & ZFS?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I'm running ZFS with de-duplication turned on (when properly tuned it works well; don't let the internet scare you). Each day I need to take several terabytes of qcow2 images and create fixed-VHDX copies of those disk images. My qcow2 images use a 2M cluster size, meaning each 2M block on the virtual disk is 2M aligned in the file. Fixed-VHDX files are just raw disk images with some metadata at the end, so they are also 2M aligned. This means when I do the conversion, ZFS can de-dupe the 2 files and I end up with only one copy of the data (yay).

That's great, but it's still CPU and IO intensive to do the conversion. Each time I want to copy a 2M block from the qcow2 image to the VHDX image I have to read the whole block byte-by-byte from the qcow2 image, then write the whole block byte-by-byte to the VHDX. Then ZFS compares the 2 blocks byte-by-byte to make sure it can de-dupe them.

It occurs to me that it *should* be possible to copy a block from one file to another without ever having to read the block. After all, each "file" is basically a bunch of pointers to blocks, each referenced by one or more files. Couldn't we just read pointers from the first file and copy them to the 2nd file without having to read the contents of the blocks they point to?

Is there some sort of system call that allows me to create a COW copy of a block-aligned extent from one file to another without having to read the contents of the file from the disk?

Comment: You're looking for reflinks".  [It's implemented for ZFS on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/reflink-3c.html) - I haven't been able to determine if it's supported by ZFS/BSD].

Comment: Plz specify programming language ... or perhaps 'unix se' would be a better place. tkx

Comment: @ValeryS. I personally am working in go, but I doubt something this low-level and os-specific will be in the language already. I expect if an answer did need to include code samples they would probably be in C. If you know how to do this in Forth, ALGOL, Java or any other programming language, I would accept that though.

Comment: @9072997: SO is dedicated to programming, not operating system issue or trouble, that was the purpose of my question. IMHO, if any, your question will not get an answer here.